# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS problem with apache2 installation

Tags: apt

I try to install an Apache2 servor on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

But the /etc/apache2 directory contain no files, only directory, and the servor can't start.

```
sudo apt install apache2 php mysql-server libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés : 
  apache2-data apache2-utils
Paquets suggérés :
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine
  | apache2-suexec-custom
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils
  libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php
  php-mysql
0 mis à jour, 7 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 357 ko dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 1 906 ko d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] o
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apache2-utils amd64 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1 [83,5 kB]
Réception de:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1 [160 kB]
Réception de:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apache2 amd64 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1 [95,1 kB]
Réception de:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php all 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 [3 212 B]
Réception de:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mysql-server all 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 [9 948 B]
Réception de:6 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php all 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 [3 084 B]
Réception de:7 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php-mysql all 1:7.2+60ubuntu1 [2 004 B]
357 ko réceptionnés en 1s (624 ko/s) 
Sélection du paquet apache2-utils précédemment désélectionné.
(Lecture de la base de données... 178177 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../0-apache2-utils_2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de apache2-utils (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Sélection du paquet apache2-data précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../1-apache2-data_2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de apache2-data (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Sélection du paquet apache2 précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../2-apache2_2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de apache2 (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Sélection du paquet libapache2-mod-php précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../3-libapache2-mod-php_1%3a7.2+60ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de libapache2-mod-php (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
Sélection du paquet mysql-server précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../4-mysql-server_5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de mysql-server (5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Sélection du paquet php précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../5-php_1%3a7.2+60ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de php (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
Sélection du paquet php-mysql précédemment désélectionné.
Préparation du dépaquetage de .../6-php-mysql_1%3a7.2+60ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de php-mysql (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour ufw (0.35-5) ...
Paramétrage de mysql-server (5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Paramétrage de libapache2-mod-php (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Paramétrage de apache2-utils (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Paramétrage de apache2-data (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Paramétrage de php (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour systemd (237-3ubuntu10) ...
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Paramétrage de php-mysql (1:7.2+60ubuntu1) ...
Paramétrage de apache2 (2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1) ...
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-05-05 09:44:51 CEST; 5ms ago
  Process: 6809 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

mai 05 09:44:50 mrouquet systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
mai 05 09:44:50 mrouquet apachectl[6809]: apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
mai 05 09:44:51 mrouquet apachectl[6809]: Action 'start' failed.
mai 05 09:44:51 mrouquet apachectl[6809]: The Apache error log may have more information.
mai 05 09:44:51 mrouquet systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
mai 05 09:44:51 mrouquet systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mai 05 09:44:51 mrouquet systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```